# How to perform a cd command and execute additional command in a new terminal from a python script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, operating-system

I am trying to run a python script on ubuntu18, which simply will open a new terminal/tab,navigate to a specific folder and then execute a command. But this simple task is looking very daunting due to my lack of knowledge.
Expected:

```
In the python script
$cd /home/metabase
$java -jar metabase.jar
```

My code:

```
try1:
cmd = "gnome-terminal --tab 'cd /home/metabase/java -jar metabase.jar; read'"
os.system(cmd)
New tab opens but nothing happens

try2:
subprocess.call(['cd /home/metabase/', 'java -jar metabase.jar'])
Error:No such file or directory
```

I tried many other combinations. But results in either new tab not opening or new tab opens but in the same directory and does nothing.
I did some reading on the problem. It seems like i am creating these subprocess and therefore when i do the CD, it does nothing. Anyways,i looked into many similar stackoverflow threads but i am still lost. Any direction would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The command to open a new `gnome-terminal` window with a bash command is:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'your command'
```

In your case:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'cd /home/metabase; java -jar metabase.jar; read'
```

Make sure this works from a shell first. Then you can invoke it from Python:

```
subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "--", "bash", "-c", "cd /home/metabase; java -jar metabase.jar; read"])
```

Comment: Awesome. It works. But the parent terminal gets closed. I want to keep it open. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change the directory ? If you want you can do it directly :

`os.system('java -jar /home/metabase/metabase.jar')` which will return the process  exit value , `0` means success.

Keep in mind that `os.system` will execute the command passed as a string in a sub-shell.

If you do not want to spawn a new shell, you can use:

`subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', '/home/metabase/metabase.jar'])` in this way there is no system shell started up, so the first argument must be a path to an executable file.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I tried suggestion from @dejdej. The problem is that, it does not open in a new terminal, although the native cmd works on the same terminal. any suggestion?